# Android Problem counting views from YouTube Android Player API

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am currently integrating my Android app with YouTube Android Player API.
To do so I followed the instructions on the following link:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

The problem is that once the integration was fully functional I tried to evaluate how the integration would affect my videos visualizations.

Does YouTube Android Player API attributes visualizations to the videos watched on it ?

How can I identify those visualizations on Youtube Analitycs ?
What is the traffic source for those visualizations ?

Comment: If I understand you right you need properties of the videos.  How you do that depends on wether you want to use a support library of some type or to build up web requests and use the api that way.  In my implementation I used a support library and it gets and posts the data.  So the answer you need kind of depends on how you want to do it.

Comment: Hello keepTrackOfYourStack, thank you for your aswer.
That was not really the issue I am having.

The problem is that when using the android youtube player wenever a user watches a video on my Android app that view is not counted on the YouTube website.

Comment: even if you play a vid on the site and go back to it the count is not incremented most of the time, just checked that.  Not sure its real time...

Comment: hello have you found the solution i still face this issue

Answer (score 0):

I found this today:

[view counts](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2991785?hl=en)

How video views are counted
JANUARY 30, 2018
We’re rolling out an update to improve system accuracy and validation of views across YouTube. You may see view fluctuations on your channel from January 29, 2018, as more or fewer views may be marked as invalid than before.
YouTube video views reflect how many times a video has been watched and can be an important measure of a video's overall popularity.

We want to make sure that videos are being viewed by actual humans and not computer programs. During the first couple of hours after a video has been published, we'll only show views that our systems believe to be valid. This might not yet show all legitimate views at that time.

After quality views are counted, view count updates more frequently. The process of including all quality views can take some time depending on a video's popularity and viewership. Afterward, the view count updates more frequently, but keep in mind that we're constantly validating views, so view count can always be adjusted.

Frozen view count
On some videos, the view count might seem frozen or not show all the views that you expect. Video views are algorithmically validated to maintain fair and positive experiences for content creators, advertisers, and users. To verify that views are real and accurate, YouTube may temporarily slow down, freeze, or adjust the view count, as well as discard low-quality playbacks.

Check views with YouTube Analytics
If you're looking at a video you uploaded, you can monitor your views more closely using YouTube Analytics. However, keep in mind that the Realtime report only shows estimates of potential view activity and might not match the number you see on the watch page.